# Basic LINQ to SQL GridView binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm completely new to using LINQ to SQL (but familiar with LINQ to objects) and I'm curious why the following piece of code throws no exception or errors, but does not create a GridView and bind data to it.

This is in the Page_Load event of a webform:

```
ContactsDataContext db = new ContactsDataContext();
db.Contacts.Where(x => x.Phone.Length > 0);
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = db.Contacts;
gv.DataBind();
```

If I drag and drop and GridView in the designer and set the DataSource as LINQ to SQL it works as expected.
Markup for LinqDataSource

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" 
ContextTypeName="LinqExample.ContactsDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
TableName="Contacts">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

Contacts is the only table in the .dbml file.  What am I missing?

Comment: You want to have the GridView in the aspx file and bind the data in the codebehind without `asp:LinqDataSource`?

Comment: So no dynamically creating GridViews and binding them to LINQ queries?

Comment: If you create it dynamically you still have to add it to the `Response`. So you want it to be both in the cs file? But if so, where in the html do you want the table with the data?

Comment: @Rudy this is literally the first time that I've played with LINQ to SQL and tried to use it to bind data to a web form.  This was mainly an exercise in "why doesn't this work like using a IDataReader object in that you can create a GridView dynamically and have it bind correctly.

Comment: I understand, but this:`GridView gv = new GridView();` will create it in memory, not on the page. If this is just an exercise, then Cam's answer is correct, the `.ToList()` was missing.

Comment: Rudy's point is valid; having created a new instance of a GridView, are you adding it to the page or a container on the page ? If not, it's never going to render.

Comment: Added additional step to add GridView to Control collection per comments above (which are correct too)

Comment: Webforms is really cool in that you can just drop a grid view on a page and have it generate a bunch of code, but on the other hand providing a datasource to a grid in this fashion couldn't be more wrong. You shouldn't be newing up DB contexts all over the code behinds. You should have a repository or services which provide reuse and encapsulate some of the functionality. Furthermore, Webforms promotes a lot of sloppy coding, and newbies don't learn to code the right way. If you care about your skill you should take note of that.

Answer (score 3):

Call the ToList() of your query. Also, your filtering is incorrect. You need to set your filter to a variable. You can't just call Where(). As your code is now, you would be returning all the contact records in your table. Also, you need to add your GridView to a control already on the page.

```
ContactsDataContext db = new ContactsDataContext();
var filteredContacts = db.Contacts.Where(x => x.Phone.Length > 0);
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = filteredContacts.ToList();
gv.DataBind();
this.Controls.Add(gv);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the link below it looks like you need to create a function for your LINQ command that would return LIST type and then have that called:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)  
        {  
            gvitems.DataSource = GetItemsRecord();  
            gvitems.DataBind();  

        }  

    }  

    public List<ITEM> GetItemsRecord()  
    {  
        BindGridViewDataContext db = new BindGridViewDataContext();  
        var listitemsrecord = (from x in db.ITEMs select x).ToList<ITEM>();  
        return listitemsrecord;  

    }
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/70dbe6/how-to-bind-gridview-using-linq-to-sql/